# Calling abort method of AbortableAsyncResult instance causes "RuntimeError: RPC backend missing task request for task_id"

Tags: celery, celery-task, celeryd

I try to implement a working example with abortable tasks in celery (5.1.2) (code snippet bellow). When I call "abort" method on AbortableAsyncResult instance exception "RuntimeError: RPC backend missing task request for {task_id}" is raised.

What do I do wrong? Why the code snippet does not work?

I was trying to google the answer but got only links to old celery issues that mention that AbortableTask will be removed in celery 4.0.0 (I'm using celery 5.1.2, and AbortableTask is present there).

```py
from time import sleep
from celery import Celery
from celery.contrib.abortable import AbortableTask

celery_app = Celery(
    broker = "amqp://login:pass@rabbitmq:5672"
    backend = "rpc://"
    include = ["root.subpath.my_tasks_module"]

@celery_app.task(acks_late=True, bind=True, base=AbortableTask)
def my_task(self, a, b):
    sleep(100)
    if self.is_aborted():
        return None
    return a * b

def foo():
    abortable_async_result = my_task.delay(4, 4)
    sleep(10)
    abortable_async_result.abort()  # This call raises exception
```

Thanks for your attention and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing RPC backend with database backend makes it work.

Initially I didn't read the [note](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.contrib.abortable.html#:%7E:text=Note,the%20database%20backends.) in AbortableTask documentation carefully:

> In order to abort tasks, there needs to be communication between the producer and the consumer. This is currently implemented through the database backend. Therefore, this class will only work with the database backends.